# One To Many query in HQL

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, hql

I have two entities, Company:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
public class Company {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
private List<CompanyRelation> companyRelations;

private String name;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
```

and CompanyRelation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company_relations")
public class CompanyRelation {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@OneToOne
private Company relatedCompany;
```

How can i build hql query to get CompanyRelation using companyId and relatedCompanyId? Something like that:

```
CompanyRelation findByCompanyIds(Long companyId, Long relatedCompanyId);
```

Comment: is there a company_id foreign key on company_relations table?

Comment: That's the point. :D It is generated on table, but it's not available in code.

Comment: I believe the second annotation is @ManyToOne! Is it not so?

Comment: There should be @ManyToOne annotation in CompanyRelation which refers to Company?

Comment: since the relation CompanyRelation - Company is BIDIRECTIONAL there should be a `ManyToOne` with mappedBy specified. Any JPA docs would tell you this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me start with the suggestion. [Based on this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) I would suggest that you map your **@OneToMany association bidirectionally** as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
public class Company {
   //..
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "relatedCompany", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<CompanyRelation> companyRelations = new ArrayList<>();
   //..
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "company_relations")
public class CompanyRelation {

//..

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
   private Company relatedCompany;

//..

}
```

Essentially let the **ToMany** side own the association as it is in the DB as well (company_id foreign key column on the company_relations table)

With that in mind you can fetch a CompanyRelation based on the Company Id with the below JPQL:

```
List<CompanyRelation> companyRelations = entityManager.createQuery(
"select cr from CompanyRelation cr where cr.relatedCompany.id = :companyId", CompanyRelation.class)
.setParameter("companyId", myCompanyId).getResultList();
```